# Any way to stop a thread that implements Runnable using a boolean , without extending Thread ?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the code :

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

    private volatile static boolean running = true;

    public void stopThread()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (running)
        {
            try {

                System.out.println("Sleeping ...");
                Thread.sleep(15000);
                System.out.println("Done sleeping ...");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.run();
    }

}
```

Is it possible to stop a thread that implements Runnable with a boolean , without extending Thread ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. In your example, you can just call `stopThread()` on any instance of `MyThread`. What more is involved that prevents that from working?

Comment: What do you want to do that your code doesn't do?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to stop a thread that implements Runnable

A class that implements `Runnable` is not a thread. It is just a plain class with no magic to it, declaring a single `void run()` method. Your example therefore doesn't start any threads.

So instead of misleadingly naming your class `MyThread`, you should name it `MyTask` and *pass* it to a `Thread` constructor:

```
final MyTask task = new MyTask();
new Thread(task).start();
Thread.sleep(2000);
task.stopRunning(); // renamed from stopThread
```

Also, do make the running flag an *instance* variable. Each `MyTask` should have its own running flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyThread myt = new MyThread();
(new Thread(myt)).start();
```

Later call

```
myt.stopThread();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the [built in interrupt mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) which does basically the same thing you're trying to implement.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleeping ...");
                Thread.sleep(15000);
                System.out.println("Done sleeping ...");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // This means someone called thread.interrupt() while you were sleeping
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // You didn't extend Thread, you implemented Runnable:
        Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        // thread.run() is synchronous, for this (the main) thread to continue use:
        thread.start();

        ...

        thread.interrupt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The `Runnable` code you have above is almost correct, but you should probably make the `running` field not static. The way you create your `Thread` needs an extra step, though. It should be:

```
Runnable r = new MyThread(); // MyThread already implements Runnable instead of extending Thread, so that's correct.
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start(); // not t.run() or r.run(), that would execute the code synchronously
r.stopThread(); // when needed
```